# React compare or match two dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime, compare

I am facing an issue in React JS. I want to do compare or match the `start_date` with `header date`

Rest API

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"staff_name": "Jill",
"custom_service_name": "Jone",
"start_date": "2020-05-06 11:30:00",
"end_date": "2020-05-06 11:45:00",
},
{
"id": "2",
"staff_name": "james",
"custom_service_name": "smith",
"start_date": "2020-05-06 11:00:00",
"end_date": "2020-05-06 11:15:00",
}
]
```

console.log data:

```
1:00 AM   //start_date
["9:43:36 AM", "9:13:36 AM", "10:13:36 AM"]    //header_date
12:00 PM
["9:43:36 AM", "9:13:36 AM", "10:13:36 AM"]    //header_date
2:15 AM
["9:43:36 AM", "9:13:36 AM", "10:13:36 AM"]    //header_date
```

My Code:

```
var currentdate = new Date();  //header_date logic
var prevdate = new Date();
var firstdate = new Date();
prevdate.setTime(currentdate.getTime() - (30 * 60 * 1000));
firstdate.setTime(currentdate.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
var current = currentdate.toLocaleTimeString();
var previous = prevdate.toLocaleTimeString();
var first = firstdate.toLocaleTimeString();


    var headerdate = [previous ,current, first];


    this.state = {
      headerdate:headerdate,
      appointmentdata:[]
    }


componentDidMount() {    //get start_date
    axios.get(`http://localhost/route/v1/appointment`)
      .then(res => {
        const appointmentdata = res.data;
        console.log(appointmentdata);
        this.setState({ appointmentdata });
      })
  }
```

I try , but this logic is not working

```
render() { return ( 
  <div>
    {this.state.appointmentdata.map(data => 
    { const dateTime = moment(data.start_date.toString()); 
      if (dateTime.format("h:mm A") === this.state.headerdate) 
      { 
        return <p>{dateTime.format("h:mm A")}</p>; } //return the match date 
      else { return null; } })}
```

Demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-browser-9e3g4

What should i do?
Can anyone help me

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: ok sure [@palaѕн](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823841/pala%d1%95%d0%bd)

Comment: You should have same format in comparison. `headerdate` is `["9:43:36 AM"` per your logs but its compared to `.format("h:mm A")`

Comment: can should i do? can you write the code? [@rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh)

Comment: have you understand the issue? [@palaѕн](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823841/pala%d1%95%d0%bd)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-browser-9e3g4  [@palasH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823841/pala%d1%95%d0%bd)

Comment: i make an example code you can check [@palaѕн](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823841/pala%d1%95%d0%bd)

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using Moment. So you can use `isSame` built-in helper from them to achieve this.

Docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/

Example code:

```
const isSameDate = (start_date, header_date) => {
  const startDate = moment(start_date);
  const headerDate = moment(header_date);

  return startDate.isSame(headerDate, 'day');
}
```

One small tip, you should move the date checking outside the `render` method, that would makes your code easier to read and maintainable

Comment: but i match or compare this code with my data `start_date` or `header date` [@Hong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599144/duc-hong)

Comment: can you tell me how can i do this ? with my data [@Hong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599144/duc-hong)

Comment: I've just modified my answer to match with your context. Make sure `start_date` and `header_date` is just a simple datetime string

Comment: Ok let me check [@Duc Hong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599144/duc-hong)

Comment: i try your code but date format issue [@Duc Hong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599144/duc-hong)

Comment: start_date `2020-05-07 02:15:00`   header date `["11:57:16 AM", "11:27:16 AM"]` [@Duc hong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599144/duc-hong)

Comment: how can compare both dates with `same format` ? can write the code please? @Duc Hong[](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599144/duc-hong)

Comment: your date format must be valid, I can tell your `start_date` and `header_date` is not the same, you should correct this first. A date string returned by server might look like this `2020-02-11T09:43:03.362530Z` (ISO String)

Comment: bro i try your example but i can't comparing two dates `start_date` and `header_date` using moment